# Android/Java: Check if arraylist is empty and then launch another activity

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

Im trying to build this Quiz program where a person is asked a question from and then has to answer, it's a game for two persons, and they just go through all the questions and the game ends.

What i've managed to make so far is the general code for loading the array (the array in the strings.xml file) into an arraylist and then take a random id from 0 to arraylist.size and then show that string (Questions) then it deletes the random id and takes a new one.

But when ive run through all the id's in the arraylist the program crashes, my code looks like this: http://pastebin.com/MaEj49BL

The important part is this:

```
public void gameCode()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    if (mList == null) 
{
     String[] mQuestions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mQuestions);
     mList = new ArrayList();
     Collections.addAll(mList, mQuestions);
}
     else if (mList.isEmpty()) 
{
     m = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         m.setText("You've run out of questions!");
}
if (wList == null) 
{
   String[] wQuestions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.wQuestions);
   wList = new ArrayList();
   Collections.addAll(wList, wQuestions);
} 
else if (wList.isEmpty()) 
{
    w = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            w.setText("You've run out of questions!");
}

    //Takes a random ID from the arraylist
    int rndm = generator.nextInt(mList.size());
    int rndw = generator.nextInt(wList.size());


    //Sets the Strings to a random number from one of the array lists
    String qMan = (String) mList.get(rndm);
    String qWoman = (String) wList.get(rndw);
    if(i == 0)
        {
            //Defines that w is textView1 with the value of qWoman
            w = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            w.setText(qWoman);
            wList.remove(rndw);
            i = 1;
            final Button buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
            buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    gameCode();
                }
            });
        }
    else
        {

            m = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            m.setText(qMan);
            mList.remove(rndm);
            i = 0;
            final Button buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
            buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    gameCode();
                }
            });
       }

}
```

}

There is comments in the source code from the pastebin. Right now I just need to to change the text to "You've run out of questions"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're checking whether or not the 2 arrays are empty but you're not short-circuiting the remainder of the logic when they are...

if mList and wList are empty, you should bypass the remainder of the method or, at a minimum, check that `mList.size() > 0` `and wList.size()>0` before trying to get the next random question from each array.

Comment: The program is running just fine, the point where is crashes is when I run out of items in the arraylist.

Comment: Right. So when you don't have any more items in the array lists you're still executing the code that tries to randomly select a question and set the question text into the views. As an example: let's say that you have 0 items in the wList and i==0, then the random number generator would return 0 and your attempt to do wList.get(rdmn) would blow up.

Comment: Thanks.. I added a if statement before the random generator etc.   and it worked like a charm`code` if (mList.size() > 0 && wList.size() > 0)

Answer (score 1):

Use CollectionUtils.isEmpty() which is null safe

Comment: should I use this on the else if statement?